# What does Jane Austen mean by the word 'alloy' in Sense and Sensibility?

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-choice, word-usage, is-it-a-word

As dear Austen had written on page 6, volume 1, chapter 1, I quote - 
"But in sorrow she must be equally carried away by her fancy, and as far beyond consolation as in pleasure she was beyond alloy. "

Comment: Related question: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/215432/the-meaning-of-alloy-in-jane-austens-emma-chapter-i?rq=1
When happy, she never let anything spoil her pleasure.